# .smbdelete files from Word 2016 for Mac on Mac OS 10.13 file server

Tags: macos, high-sierra, ms-office, mojave, smb

I am working with a Mac mini (Macmini7,1) running High Sierra 10.13.6 with SMB file sharing to a few connected computers. Things have been working fine, but since updating a couple of the client machines to Mojave 10.14, when saving changes to MS Word documents we get a "Grant File Access" dialogue wanting to access a file named .smbdeleteAAAABBBBetc

[image: Grant file access dialog]

I gather from various sources such as .smbdelete files accumulating on server share and https://discussions.apple.com/message/30046649#message30046649 that these files are the result of the SMB client trying to be careful when it deletes a file (basically rather than delete the file, it is first renamed and hidden to perhaps make it easier to deal with multiple processes acting on the file and locking issues and stuff like that)

Apple introduced this behavior in OS X 10.10 you can find it in the source code here:

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/smb/smb-759.40.1/kernel/smbfs/smbfs_smb.c

The comment above the code that does it is:

- We have an open file that they want to delete. Use the NFS silly rename
- trick, but try to do better than NFS. The picking of the name came from the
- NFS code. So we first open the file for deletion. Now come up with a new
- name and rename the file. Make the file hidden if we can. Now lets mark
- it for deletion and close the file. If the rename fails then the whole call
- should fail. If the mark for deletion call fails just set a flag on the
- vnode and delete it when we close.
  In our situation, almost every time a MS Word document is saved after a change has been made, this type of dialogue pops up: Grant File Access dialogue

Since the .smbdelete file is hidden, one cannot select it if you hit the "Select..." button. Hitting "Cancel" results in MS word editing the .smbdelete file, which we can't do anything with other than 'Save As' and rename.

We've set our permissions on the volume to read/write for everyone in the office and propagated to subfolders via 'Get info' GUI and terminal, and none of this appears to affect the permissions on these temp files that Word creates.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.